# Why does TypedDict alt syntax work for illegal names?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from typing import TypedDict, Optional

# This will work
Overview = TypedDict('Overview', {'detail.id': Optional[str]})

# This will throw an error
# SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation
class Overview(TypedDict):
    'detail.id': Optional[str]
```

This is on Python 3.8.9

Is there any way to make the latter syntax work?

Comment: The documentation says: *"The functional syntax should also be used when any of the keys are not valid identifiers, for example because they are keywords or contain hyphens."* So the implication is no, you can't use the dataclass-style syntax if your keys aren't valid identifiers (in your case, because of the `.`). https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict

Comment: Classes can't change the basic syntax of the language. And the language syntax only allows identifiers, not strings, in the second style.

Comment: This isn't unique to `TypedDict`; it's a general result of Python syntax restricting certain constructs to valid identifiers,  not general strings. For example, `setattr(x, "foo.bar", 5)` is legal, but you can only access it with, e.g., `getattr(x, "foo.bar")`, not `x.foo.bar` or `x."foo.bar"`, etc.